# tar in Azure Pipelines on Windows agent fails with "Cannot connect to D: resolve failed"

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, tar

I'm baffled by an error I'm getting from a Windows agent (build worker) on Azure Pipelines.  This task is failing:

```
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: 'Unpack source tarball'
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            Set-PSDebug -Trace 1
            tar -zxf $(Pipeline.Workspace)\objconv-$(o.version).tar.gz
```

with this output:

```
DEBUG:    3+  >>>> tar -zxf D:\a\1\objconv-2.51.tar.gz
tar (child): Cannot connect to D: resolve failed

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
/usr/bin/tar: Child returned status 128
/usr/bin/tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

"D:\a\1" is the expansion of the $(Pipeline.Workspace) variable.  I'm suspicious of some kind of Unix-software-not-fully-ported-to-Windows issue because tar seems to be identifying itself as "/usr/bin/tar" instead of, I dunno, "C:\Windows\PowerShell-Components\tar.exe", but beyond that I got nothing.

What on earth does "Cannot connect to D: resolve failed" mean and how do I fix the task?

(Full azure-pipelines.yml visible here: https://bitbucket.org/elwoz/objconv/src/trunk/azure-pipelines.yml )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the [Extract Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/extract-files?view=azure-devops) task instead of rolling your own. I expect you're seeing an issue with `tar` expecting Unix-style paths and not being able to handle Windows-style paths.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to admit I would never have thought of looking for a task for this, because _of course_ you do it with a script step?  You can tell I've spent my entire professional life in the Unix world.  Anyway, it works, thanks.